# Jquery Slideshow Script, Pause on Click

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm very new to jquery and javascript in general, so sorry if this is a simple question.  Any help would be hugely appreciated. I have a slideshow auto-paging and I want it so when you click on the controller (#thumbs li) the show pauses.  Here's the JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var currentImage;
var currentIndex = -1;
var interval;
function showImage(index){
    if(index < $('#bigPic div').length){
        var indexImage = $('#bigPic div')[index]
        if(currentImage){   
            if(currentImage != indexImage ){
                $(currentImage).css('z-index',2);
                clearTimeout(myTimer);
                $(currentImage).fadeOut(400, function() {
                    myTimer = setTimeout("showNext()", 3500);
                    $(this).css({'display':'none','z-index':1})
                });
            }
        }
        $(indexImage).css({'display':'block', 'opacity':1});
        currentImage = indexImage;
        currentIndex = index;
        $('#thumbs li').removeClass('active');
        $($('#thumbs li')[index]).addClass('active');
    }
}

function showNext(){
    var len = $('#bigPic div').length;
    var next = currentIndex < (len-1) ? currentIndex + 1 : 0;
    showImage(next);
}

var myTimer;

$(document).ready(function() {
    myTimer = setTimeout("showNext()", 3500);
    showNext(); //loads first image
    $('#thumbs li').bind('click',function(e){
        var count = $(this).attr('rel');
        showImage(parseInt(count)-1);
    });
});


</script>
```

Comment: Just so you know, there is a jQuery plugin called Lightbox Slideshow (http://www.justinbarkhuff.com/lab/lightbox_slideshow/) which provides all this functionality and more. It's good you're learning this on your own, too. But, I wanted to let you know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a function to start the slide show as well as stop so something like this.

```
// must be set to declare that we're using it later.
var myTimer;

function startShow(){
  myTimer = setTimeout("showNext()", 3500);
}
function stopShow(){
  clearTimeout(myTimer);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   startShow();
   showNext(); //loads first image
  $('#thumbs li').bind('click',function(e){
       var count = $(this).attr('rel');
       showImage(parseInt(count)-1);
   });
  // you're going to want to hide this element initially, until the user pauses the slide show, vice versa.
  $('#selectorToStartShow').bind('click',function(){
     startShow();
  });
  $('#selectorToPauseShow').bind('click',function(){
     stopShow();
  });
});
```

i'm not sure what you're trying to do with the #thumbs li click, however that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'm very close, but for some reason I have to click the stop button twice.

Comment: After adding the snippet above?